# inconsistencies in timeit() on Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, timeit

I was using Jupyter Notebooks with Python 3.6.  If you want to use `timeit()` in the simplest way possible for a quick test, it seems like, for the most part, if you use it as the only line in a cell and put a function call in it, it works, as in:

```
timeit(raiseTo600(6623))
```

If you put so much as a comment in the same cell with the command, you get an error, which is why the function being called is defined in a previous cell (put it int the same cell and you get an error).

Even this behavior (where it works), is not 100% consistent.  Randomly, errors can occur and to clear them, you have to restart the kernel and then it works again.

I have seen examples online that accepted more than a single function call within `timeit()` (multi-lines of code presented within quotes).  I wanted to put a comment in the cell the code, and thought that since the  error I get with comments is that timeit is not recognized, maybe including an import statement would fix it.  But attempts to do this trigger errors again:

code:

```
from timeit import timeit
timeit(raiseTo600(6623))
```

output:

```
ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable
```

Putting it within quotes creates this error even though the function was run in a previous cell and is working fine. Revised code:

```
from timeit import timeit
timeit('raiseTo600(6623)')
```

Output:

```
NameError: name 'raiseTo600' is not defined
```

This should be simple to use.  What is going wrong here?

I have tested this with multiple functions and gotten the same symptoms, but for completeness, here is the simple one I was attempting to use to just shake out why `timeit()` was not working:

```
def raiseTo600(x): 
    return x**600
```

Answer (score 0):

Within Jupyter notebooks, it's best to use the built-in `%%timeit` magic:

```
In [1]: 
        %%timeit -n 1000 def raiseTo600(x): return x**600
        raiseTo600(6623)

Out [1]: 
        7.59 µs ± 699 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The first line of the cell is executed, but not timed.  You can set flags for `timeit` and/or run setup code (such as defining your function).  The main body of the cell is then looped and timed.

From the [Jupyter docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#line-magics):

> %timeit Time execution of a Python statement or expression
>
> Usage, in line mode:
>
> > %timeit [-n -r [-t|-c] -q -p -o] statement
>
> or in cell mode:
>
> > %%timeit [-n -r [-t|-c] -q -p -o] setup_code
> >
> > code
> >
> > code...
>
> Time execution of a Python statement or expression using the timeit module. This function can be used both as a line and cell magic:
>
> In line mode you can time a single-line statement (though multiple ones can be chained with using semicolons).
>   In cell mode, the statement in the first line is used as setup code (executed but not timed) and the body of the cell is timed. The cell body has access to any variables created in the setup code.